# accessing unexported function in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to run a moving average (preferably witch custom weights) on a `data.table` object. `frollmean` is very fast compared to `frollapply` (especially) and even `TTR::EMA` (which does not allow custom weights but only wilder=T/F)--performance comparison at the end. I tried to use `data.table:::froll` (which `frollmean` uses and is not exported). It's first argument must be the (character) name of the function (for `frollmean` it is `mean`).

```
data.table:::froll('f.roll', x$c, 10)
Error in data.table:::froll("f.roll", x$c, 10) : 
  Internal error: invalid fun argument in rolling function, should have been caught before. please report to data.table issue tracker.
```

I tried to access the data.table package as an environment:

```
e.dt <- as.environment('package:data.table')
e.dt$froll <- data.table:::froll
Error in e.dt$froll <- data.table:::froll (from c.ta.R#287) : 
  cannot add bindings to a locked environment
e.dt2 <- new.env(parent=e.dt)
e.dt2$froll <- data.table:::froll
e.dt2$froll('f.roll', top.., n, na.rm=T)
Error in e.dt2$froll("f.roll", x$c, n, na.rm = T) : 
  Internal error: invalid fun argument in rolling function, should have been caught before. please report to data.table issue tracker.
```

I also tried attaching my custom function `f.roll` to `e.dt2`:

```
e.dt2$f.roll <- f.roll
e.dt2$froll('f.roll', top.., n, na.rm=T)
Error in e.dt2$froll("f.roll", top.., n, na.rm = T) : 
  Internal error: invalid fun argument in rolling function, should have been caught before. please report to data.table issue tracker.
```

`froll` calls a C function (`CfrollfunR`):

```
data.table:::froll
function (fun, x, n, fill = NA, algo = c("fast", "exact"), align = c("right", 
    "left", "center"), na.rm = FALSE, hasNA = NA, adaptive = FALSE) 
{
    stopifnot(!missing(fun), is.character(fun), length(fun) == 
        1L, !is.na(fun))
    algo = match.arg(algo)
    align = match.arg(align)
    ans = .Call(CfrollfunR, fun, x, n, fill, algo, align, na.rm, 
        hasNA, adaptive)
    ans
}
<bytecode: 0x0000000013738b40>
<environment: namespace:data.table>

data.table:::CfrollfunR
$name
[1] "CfrollfunR"

$address
<pointer: 0x000000001ef93e80>
attr(,"class")
[1] "RegisteredNativeSymbol"

$dll
DLL name: datatable
Filename: C:/bin/cygwin/cygwin64/home/Adi/R/win-library/4.0/data.table/libs/x64/datatable.dll
Dynamic lookup: FALSE

$numParameters
[1] -1

attr(,"class")
[1] "CallRoutine"      "NativeSymbolInfo"
```

However, while my custom function `f.roll` doesnt' work, `mean` as the first parameter works:

```
tail(e.dt2$froll('mean', x$c, 10, na.rm=T))
[1] 43.506 43.148 42.855 42.548 42.331 42.200
```

I inspected the data.table DLL `C:\bin\cygwin\cygwin64\home\Adi\R\win-library\4.0\data.table\libs\x64\datatable.dll` (using `DLL Export Viewer`) but it doesn't show any function called `mean`. `data.table` package also doesn't have any `mean` function (either exported or not exported).

```
data.table:::mean
Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'mean' not found
data.table::mean
Error: 'mean' is not an exported object from 'namespace:data.table'
```

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

PS Here's the performance comparison from `microbenchmark` for reference:

```
## Unit: milliseconds
##        expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
##  frollapply 131736.6469 131736.6469 131736.6469 131736.6469 131736.6469 131736.6469     1
##         EMA    262.9931    262.9931    262.9931    262.9931    262.9931    262.9931     1
##   frollmean     97.0388     97.0388     97.0388     97.0388     97.0388     97.0388     1
```

PS Since `froll` isn't a solution to my problem (as @Waldi points out) I'm looking for an alternate solution but I left this as is and asked a separate, new question: [fast way to calculate moving average/rolling function which allows custom weights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73675740/fast-way-to-calculate-moving-average-rolling-function-which-allows-custom-weight)

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out where `f.roll` comes from and if you want to copy `froll` why not use `getAnywhere` or `fixInNamespace`?

Comment: ```f.roll``` is just a custom function that does something like this:

Comment: @IRTFM, thanks for your input. ```f.roll``` is just a custom function that does something like this (simplified): ```f.roll <- function(x, weights) mean(weights*x)```
weights simply apply more weight to the most "recent" rows (assuming a time series). 

```getAnywhere(froll)``` finds it (although I had already found it, ```data.table:::froll```). I thought of ```fixInNamespace``` but didnt' give it a try since it seems it *edits* an existing function and since ```froll``` calls a C function, ```CfrollfunR```, which is really the main, workhorse function I didn't thik it would work.

Comment: If your custom function is written in C, then we could try to make it work, otherwise no way. Be sure to upvote/create FR requesting this functionality, so it can eventually be added. There is now pending PR that adds many features to rolling functions, for details see last entry in new features in news.md in this branch https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/frollmax/NEWS.md

Comment: @jangorecki I appreciate the offer to incorporate that into ```data.table``` (really wonderful package!). 1) I'm already working on an improved R solution at the moment (that I'll post in my the related question) that shows promise. Writing it in C will most likely be faster and I plan to get back to writing it in C after I get my project up and running (since I haven't written any C for R yet, I put that on the back burner for now).

Comment: 2) the code should be pretty simple and easily to integrate with the existing C code. For example, ```frollmean``` could take an optional argument ```weights``` and, for example, in ```froll.c``` (function ```frollmeanFast```), when it's not NULL instead of ```w += x[i]``` it would be ```w += weights[i]*x[i]``` and then instead of ```w/k``` it would be ```w/sum(weights)```. ```weights``` would need to be a vector of the same length as the sliding window (if bigger truncated to that size if smaller it should just be padded with the last value).

Comment: If you could make the related changes that would be great if not maybe I'll get back to make them and suggest them after I get my project up and running.

Comment: @jangorecki what data.table's ```froll``` functions implement (the non-weighted (rolling) mean) is just a special case of the weighted version when all weights are equal to 1 (```weights <- rep(1, k)``` (```k``` being the window size). Then ```sum(weights)==k``` and ```w/k``` applies but if weights are not all 1 then ```sum(weights[i]*x[i])/sum(weights)``` applies (which would make it a weighted mean). For example, ```weights <- c(2, 1, 1, 1)``` would just give the first value in the sliding window double the weight of the other values. So it's just a matter of making the formula more generic.

Comment: Making more generic will just make it slower, no? To not impose an overhead on mean we need to branch to a new weighted mean loop.

Comment: @jangorecki yes, agreed, it makes more sense to branch out to a new weighted mean loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C` [source code](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/c4a2085e35689a108d67dacb2f8261e4964d7e12/src/frollR.c) of `froll`, shows that this internal function is only designed for  `mean` or `sum`, the error isn't linked to the environment :

```
enum {MEAN, SUM} sfun;
  if (!strcmp(CHAR(STRING_ELT(fun, 0)), "mean")) {
    sfun = MEAN;
  } else if (!strcmp(CHAR(STRING_ELT(fun, 0)), "sum")) {
    sfun = SUM;
  } else {
    error(_("Internal error: invalid %s argument in %s function should have been caught earlier. Please report to the data.table issue tracker."), "fun", "rolling"); // # nocov
  }
```

Comment: thanks. That explains why the function was not then exported. I looked further in the C code and and although there are no C functions ```mean``` or ```sum``` the name in the argument points to C specific functions such as ```fadaptiverollmean```. Thus, you are right, it doesn't work with a custom functions but only with ```mean``` and ```sum`` because there is C code for these only.