# fast way to calculate moving average/rolling function which allows custom weights

Tags: r, data.table, moving-average, rolling-computation

One can use `TTR:SMA()` or `TTR::EMA()` but these do not allow custom weights. One solution I came up with is using `data.table::frollapply`:

```
library(data.table)
x <- data.table(type=rep(1:100, 10000), val=sample(1:1000000, 1000000))

my.roll.2 <- function(x, weights=NULL) {
    n <- length(x)
    if(is.null(weights)) weights <- 1/(1:n)
    sum(weights[1:n]*x, na.rm=T)/sum(weights[1:n])
}

my.roll.1 <- function(x, n, name, ref.col, val.col, weights=NULL) {
    x[, (name) := frollapply(get(val.col), n, my.roll.2, weights=weights), by=ref.col]
}
```

However the performance of `my.roll.1` is not great (and it gets exponentially worse compared to the other ones the bigger the input data):

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(TTR)
n <- 10
name <- 'test'
microbenchmark(
    my.roll=my.roll.1(x, n, name, 'type', 'val')
  , frollmean=x[, (name):=data.table::frollmean(val, n), type]
  , EMA=x[, (name):=TTR::EMA(val, n), type]
  , times=10L
)
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
   my.roll 7661.0278 7666.0732 7698.69693 7693.28025 7708.6880 7778.6171    10
 frollmean   17.1724   17.6321   19.54878   19.56485   20.9490   23.5549    10
       EMA   43.0090   43.7332   45.92251   45.79210   47.2391   51.9399    10
```

`data.table::frollmean` is very fast (implemented in C) but it doesn't use any weights. `TTR::EMA` uses only the EMA specific weights/smoothing (the only flexibility is to use the parameter `wilder=TRUE` or `wilder=FALSE`). My need is to achieve the functionality of `my.roll.1` but to be faster.

Comment: Is this comparable? https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5295

Comment: The base `filter` function does a similar calculation.

Comment: You could check out the `runner` package which I've used before for rolling window calculations.  Or you could write your own function in c++ and invoke `Rcpp` magic.

Comment: @M.Viking thanks, I didn't know about ```stats::weighted.mean()```. I need to use it in conjunction with ```data.table::frollapply()``` like my ```my.roll.2``` function but it has a bit better performance (5.6 sec vs. 7.7 sec). It's still far away from ```TTR::EMA()``` or ```data.table::frollmean()```. But it's still an improvement over my function.

Comment: @user2554330 are you referring to ```dplyr::filter()``` or ```stats::filter``` or something else? That's all I found with ```getAnywhere(filter)```. Also could you give a brief example? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelDewaro I tried out ```runner```:
```x[, (name):=runner(val, k=n, f=my.roll.2), type]```
but the performance is even worse than my function (9.9 sec vs. 7.7 sec). I guess C would be the way. While I use some C code with Rcpp I've never written any C for R and I think mentally it's easier to look for a solution in what you are more familiar with (straight R). But I can write C so it shouldn't be that hard. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: as suggested by @user2554330, you could have a look at `stats::filter` or `signal::filter`, because weighted mean is an [FIR filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_impulse_response)

Comment: @AdrianChira:  I was suggesting `stats::filter`.  I can't give an example, because I don't know what your code is trying to do:  `my.roll.2` doesn't calculate a moving average, and I'm not familiar enough with `data.table` to know what you're calculating there.

Comment: @user2554330 thanks for the clarification. ```my.roll.2``` does calculate a moving average. ```data.table::frollapply``` feeds ```my.roll.2``` chunks of ```x``` of the length of the window size (```n```) for each row so the ```mean``` calculated by ```my.roll.2``` ends up being the mean over a rolling window (aka, moving average).

Comment: @user2554330 actually I had a bug in my code and the weights were not applied properly (a plain ```mean((weights[1:n]*x)``` doesnt' work as intended) it needs to be ```sum(weights[1:n]*x)/sum((weights[1:n])```. I fixed that now. ```mean()``` would only work if ```weights==rep(1, n)```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, a possible solution using `stats::filter`.

Note following arguments:

- sides = 1 so that the filter uses past values only
- coefficients order inverted `1/(n:1)` because filter calculation starts with most recent value

```
my.roll[,test2:=filter(val,prop.table(1/n:1),sides=1),by=.(type)]
# Conversion from ts to numeric
my.roll[,test2:=as.numeric(test2)][]

# type    val     test    test2
# <int>  <int>    <num>    <num>
#       1:     1 955625       NA       NA
#       2:     2 979596       NA       NA
#       3:     3 578778       NA       NA
#       4:     4 174631       NA       NA
#       5:     5 459947       NA       NA
# ---                               
#  999996:    96 191233 620505.8 620505.8
#  999997:    97 626522 398615.6 398615.6
#  999998:    98 527846 565061.2 565061.2
#  999999:    99 480277 537305.9 537305.9
# 1000000:   100 757433 395458.3 395458.3

all.equal(my.roll$test,my.roll$test2)
#[1] TRUE
```

Speed comparison:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  my.roll=my.roll.1(x, n, name, 'type', 'val'),
  filter={my.roll[,test2:=filter(val,prop.table(1/n:1),sides=1),by=.(type)][];
          my.roll[,test2:=as.numeric(test2)][]
          }
  , times=10L
)

Unit: milliseconds
    expr       min        lq       mean     median        uq       max neval
 my.roll 2194.3200 2203.3726 2264.67423 2245.04510 2314.2377 2401.1156    10
  filter   73.1602   76.3098   78.18358   77.25665   80.4204   85.0567    10
```

Comment: instead of the long filter, just use `filter(val, prop.table(1/n:1), sides = 1)`

Comment: @Waldi thanks (and @onyambu as well!). I tested manually and I had to change the coefficients back the  to ```1/(1:n)``` in order to achieve my request (which would be the standard case where the most recent values have more weight). So the formula that works is ```x[, test:=stats::filter(val, prop.table(1/(1:n)), sides=1), by=.(type)]```. This is indeed very fast, almost as fast as TTR::EMA.

Comment: I worked on my own second solution where I used a trick to turn the sliding window into additional columns and then do to means over rows which was much better than my initial solution but it is still about 4.5 times slower than the stats::filter solution.

Comment: @Waldi to further clarify what my earlier comment on changing the coefficients means: in my data 1st row is the oldest data and last row is the most recent. I think that's pretty standard and ```1/(1:n)``` works for that case. The ```1/(n:1)``` may work when the first row has the most recent data (although I haven't tested).

Comment: @Waldi also, I see that filter returns a time series (```ts```) object which causes issues down the road for me so.... oh, now I see why you did an ```as.numeric()```, lol. I'd put it inline: ```x[,test2:=filter(val,prop.table(1/1:n),sides=1),by=.(type)]```. Thanks again